# textbox.text gives null value if Read Only is false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textbox in my WebForm1.asp page.

First One:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="partycode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Another one is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtParty" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></asp:TextBox>
```

When I am trying to return the value using the following code:

```
string ClientCode = partycode.Text;
string ClientName = txtParty.Text;
```

partycode returns the text whatever it holds but txtParty returns null although it has some value.

Comment: Surely there is some other code which is clearing the value of txtParty. Can you look at your code and see where txtParty is used and it's Text is set.

Comment: I am returning the text value on the same button click. But only the read only textbox returns the value and the normal textbox returns null  value.

Comment: Whenever I am making the non readonly textbox to readonly= true, I am getting the values.

Comment: What if you remove read-only="true" from patrycode? Are you still getting value from partycode?

Comment: No, only the read-only field gives the proper value.  If I removed the read-only=true then I get null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `value` property of both text boxes set then the browser sends this values back to the server. So verify that.

Here example of the situation in picture. The `value` of text box is set and then it can be seen, that the browser really sends those values back to the server. So no magic, it should work. HTH

[image]